# javascript array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this piece of code that adds values to an array with an input box. I would like to save that array in `localStorage` and display the contents of the array on another page.

```
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="display">Display</button>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var inputArray = [];
    var input = document.getElementById('inputbox');
    var screen = document.getElementById('screen');

    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
        inputArray.push(input.value);
        screen.innerHTML = input.value;
    };

    document.getElementById('display').onclick = function () {
        screen.innerHTML = inputArray
    };
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly your problem now ? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: When I refresh the page the contents of the array get lost, I would like to save those contents in localstorage. So that the array doesn't get emptied on a page refresh.

Comment: Where did you implement logic of adding your array yo LocalStorage?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not persisting data in `localStorage`. As `localStorage` persist only string data, You can [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) while  storing and [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) while reading.

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var inputArray = [];

     //Check if data is persisted in localStorge then load in the array
     var str = localStorage.getItem('nyArray')
     if (str) {
         inputArray = JSON.parse(str);
     }

     var input = document.getElementById('inputbox');
     var screen = document.getElementById('screen');

     document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
         inputArray.push(input.value);
         screen.innerHTML = input.value;

         //Store stringifyed string
         localStorage.setItem('nyArray', JSON.stringify(inputArray))
     };

     document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
         screen.innerHTML = inputArray
     };
 }
```

Comment: it should be `setItem` instead of `getItem` inside of submit `click` function.

Comment: In your snippet, you spelled `localStorage` as `localStorge`

Comment: Thank guys for typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your array and then save it in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). When required, read and [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it back to array.

```
var originalArr = ["V", "A"];
var strArr = JSON.stringify(originalArr);

// to save your array
localStorage.setItem("YOUR_KEY",strArr);

// to read from localstorage
var yourOriginalArray = localStorage.getItem("YOUR_KEY");
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Global variable see below

window.savedarray= inputArray

now you  can access savedarray in other pages

Comment: Downvoted because this is not storing the array in localstorage, but simply storing it as a global variable.

Comment: Also storing a global variable (which is bad enough in itself) does not make that variable available in any other page of the site.